# How can I use Google maps data in my app

Tags: java, google-maps, project

I am doing my project(Java - Android). I did some research about Google Maps API and yet I still have no clue what should I do. Purpose of my app is to read output from google map app and transfer data to my app to perform the task. Imagine this app like a Google Maps navigation voice but I will use other method to display the output instead of the voice(Turn left in 100ft ect). Lets say I put some address and run google map navigation. I need some advice for this:

```
void myMethod()
{
    if(I am on right track && need to keep driving forward && distance < 100 ft)
    {
          //do something
    }

    if(I need to turn right in 100 ft)
    {
          //do something
    }

    if(I need to make a U-Turn)
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

Anyone can give me some suggestion how to do this such thing?

Answer (score 0):

Look up "Google Maps API for Java". It's an Google maps api for java. I believe there are tutorials on how to add it to your project and how to use it on their website. This is the website  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/mapsengine/v1.